# Hotwire Flash notification not working and not updating UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, hotwire

controller.rb

```
def create
  flash[:alert] = 'some error message'
  turbo_frame_updates
end

  private

  def turbo_frame_updates
    # Define the Turbo Frame(s) you want to update
    [
      turbo_stream.update("flash_messages") do
        render(partial: 'shared/flash_messages', formats: [:html])
      end
    ]
  end
```

_shared/flash_messages.html.erb

```
<% extend ApplicationHelper %>

<%#= turbo_stream.replace "flash_messages" do %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "flash_messages" do %>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert <%= flash_class(key) %> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= raw(value) %>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<head>
<%= turbo_stream_from :flash_messages %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'shared/flash_messages' %>
</body
```

helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def flash_class(level)
      bootstrap_alert_class = {
        "success" => "alert-success",
        "error" => "alert-danger",
        "notice" => "alert-info",
        "alert" => "alert-danger",
        "warn" => "alert-warning"
      }
      bootstrap_alert_class[level]
    end
end
```

Sending request in json format and expecting flash_messages frame to show error flash notifications.

getting below response from server:

```
<turbo-frame id="flash_messages">

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      undefined local variable or method `errors' for ActiveStorage::Blob:Class
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

</turbo-frame>
```

turbo frame is present in html

```
<turbo-frame id="flash_messages"></turbo-frame>
```

Still not updating in UI